# setInterval issue (js)

Tags: javascript, jquery, setinterval

I have been trying to fix this script for more than an hour and still can't get it to work. It is a loop performing animate and html jquery events in a setInterval.

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/GNrL3/

Here is the code (same as fiddle but some prefer to have it here):

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var i = 1;
var startinterval = 0;

$('#clickhere').click(function() {
    startinterval = setInterval("curvalues()", 1000);
});

function curvalues() {
    if ($i == 20) {
        clearInterval(startinterval);
    }
    else {
        $("#square").animate({
            "left": "+=30px"
        }, "slow");
        $("#text").html("Barracks");
        $i++;
    }
}

});

<div id="square" style="position:absolute;height:30px;width:30px;background-color:#F07014;"></div>
<br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
<div id="text" style="height:30px;width:100px;border:1px solid #000">Text box</div>
<br /><br />
<input type="button" value="Start" id="clickhere"/>
```

My belief is that the issue concerns the setInterval of the function, but still, the syntax seems good to me...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this line:

```
startinterval = setInterval("curvalues()", 1000);
```

To this:

```
startinterval = setInterval(curvalues, 1000);
```

Or this:

```
startinterval = setInterval(function() { curvalues(); callSomethingElse(); }, 1000);
```

And get rid of the `$` in front of `i`.  There's no need for that.

Comment: Btw, do you have any idea if there is a way to pause/resume the function or this is impossible to do?

Comment: To stop what `setInterval` started call `clearInterval(startinterval);`.  Though I think "startinterval" is a bad name for a variable in this case and I'd change it to something like "timer" or just "interval".

Comment: I know, but I just want to pause it and start it back again where it was paused (not from the beginning)

Comment: Then make sure your logic within the function being invoked by setInterval doesn't reset variables upon execution.

Answer (score 3):

You have a function-scope problem. Instead of this:

```
setInterval("curvalues()", 1000);
```

do this:

```
setInterval(curvalues, 1000);
```

**EDIT** You have one more mistake. Your counter variable has a wrong name. It should be declared like this:

```
var $i = 1; //You missed the '$'
```

(or reference all your vars with `i` instead of `$i`)

I updated your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/GNrL3/1/ and it works now.

Hope this helps. Cheers

Comment: Thanks! I keep learning everyday! While you're there, do you have any idea if there is a way to pause/resume the function or this is impossible to do?

Comment: @Edgar I know, but I just want to pause it and start it back again where it was paused (not from the beginning)